# need to get record count when record_type=VALID through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tibco

I have below xml data and need to get record count when **record_type=VALID** through XSLT. 
location_name and file_type are the inputs to the xslt. i have to get record count for each location_name and file_type when they were provided as inputs. **Location_Name** and **File_Type** are the variables in the XSLT.

```
<root>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>9</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>10</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>5</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>9</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>11</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>14</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>10</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
</root>
```

the expected output is Rec_count=2 for location_name=XYZ el and File_type=STOSO
                       Rec_count=3 for location_name=XYZ XYZ and File_type=STOSO

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

**The wanted XPath expressions are**:

```
count(/*/*
         [RECORD_TYPE='VALID' and LOCATION_NAME=$pLoc1 and FILE_TYPE=$pFType])
```

**and**:

```
count(/*/*
         [RECORD_TYPE='VALID' and LOCATION_NAME=$pLoc2 and FILE_TYPE=$pFType])
```

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pLoc1" select="'XYZ el'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pLoc2" select="'XYZ XYZ'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pFType" select="'STOSO'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vCount1" select=
  "count(/*/*
         [RECORD_TYPE='VALID' and LOCATION_NAME=$pLoc1 and FILE_TYPE=$pFType])"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vCount2" select=
  "count(/*/*
         [RECORD_TYPE='VALID' and LOCATION_NAME=$pLoc2 and FILE_TYPE=$pFType])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy-of select="concat($vCount1, ', ', $vCount2)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>9</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <SellOutRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>10</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SellOutRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>5</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>9</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>11</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <InventoryRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>14</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </InventoryRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
    <SalesInRecord>
        <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
        <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
        <RECORD_NO>10</RECORD_NO>
        <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
    </SalesInRecord>
</root>
```

**evaluates the two XPath expressions and copies to the output the result of this evaluation:**

```
2, 3
```

Comment: the above XML data is just a sample. i want to get the count for the location_name and file_type combination which i will pass them as inputs to xslt to get the count for that combination.

Comment: @user1658369, The transformation is doing *exactly* that -- do note that the "input" values are external (global) parameters.

Comment: but the inputs seemed to be initiated already but i want to pass them from other source in this case i will process those inputs from JDBC query ( jdbc query will have a list of location_name and file_type combinations) to xslt and it should process the count only for that combination.  i will pass only one location_name and file_type at a given time to get count for that combination and it is a of loop until the jdbc query combination ends. sorry if i couldn't understand it properly.

Comment: i am expecting something like this. i just modified your code. `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pLoc" select="/*/*[LOCATION_NAME]"/>
 <xsl:param name="pFType" select="/*/*[FILE_TYPE]"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vCount" select=
  "count(/*/*[RECORD_TYPE='VALID' and LOCATION_NAME=$pLoc1 and FILE_TYPE=$pFType])"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        error_rec_count=<xsl:copy-of select="vCount"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>` i am not sure its gonna work... thanks

Comment: @user1658369, You didn't specify in the question where the "inputs" come from -- so I supposed they are passed to the transformation as external parameters (by the invoker of the transformation). The fact that the external parameters have default values (in my code) doesn't mean that they cannot be specified and passed from outside.